# Error: Send-MailMessage Attachment Could not find file

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I am getting the below error with PowerShell Send-MailMessage command.

```
Send-MailMessage : Could not find file 'C:\ABC_$getDateTime.xls'
```

Code:

```
$getDateTime = ((get-date).ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm"))
C:\tsizepro.exe /EXCEL "C:\ABC_$getDateTime.xls" /NOGUI "\\path\path"
Send-MailMessage -From 'xyzy@xyz.com' -To 'xyz@xyz.com' -Subject "Test email for $getDateTime" -Body "Please find the attached report for $getDateTime" -Attachments "C:\ABC_$getDateTime.xls" -SmtpServer 'smtpservername'
```

When I copy the path from the error and open it in Explorer, it does open without any issue. I have tried running the PowerShell as Administrator too, but still the same error.

The PowerShell version is 4.0.

Please don't bother about the tsizepro.exe. It's just a tool that pulls a storage report and exports it in Excel.

Comment: Could it be that the filename gets altered by the tsizepro.exe tool? Or does it keep it in use? Maybe reverse the order of the lines, so first send the Excel  and then have the tool do its thing with it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$getDateTime = ((get-date).ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm"))
C:\tsizepro.exe /EXCEL "C:\ABC_$( $getDateTime ).xls" /NOGUI "\\path\path"
Send-MailMessage -From 'xyzy@xyz.com' -To 'xyz@xyz.com' -Subject "Test email for $getDateTime" -Body "Please find the attached report for $getDateTime" -Attachments "C:\ABC_$( $getDateTime ).xls" -SmtpServer 'smtpservername'
```

If this doesn't work:

```
$getDateTime = ( ( get-date ).ToString( "yyyyMMddHHmm" ) )
$fileName    = 'C:\ABC_' + $getDateTime + '.xls'
C:\tsizepro.exe /EXCEL "$fileName" /NOGUI "\\path\path"
    Send-MailMessage -From 'xyzy@xyz.com' -To 'xyz@xyz.com' -Subject "Test email for $getDateTime" -Body "Please find the attached report for $getDateTime" -Attachments "$fileName" -SmtpServer 'smtpservername'
```